# command line arguments java * is being overloaded to pick up filenames

Tags: java, shell, cmd, wildcard

I am writing the most simple calculator in java that picks up command line arguments.Everything works fine, except the multiplication function. For some reason it picks up names of the files from the current location. I have absolutely no idea why this happening, and how to turn it off...google was no help.

```
public class Calculate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(args[0] + " " + args[1] + " " + args[2]);

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("<number1> <operator> <number2>");
        } else {

            final int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            final int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            switch (args[1]) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println(num1 + num2);
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println(num1 - num2);
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.println(num1 * num2);
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.println(num1 / num2);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with java, but with the command line, you need to use:

```
java Calculate 2 "*" 3
```

The reason is that `*` is interpreted by the command line as a *wildcard*: it is replaced by all files in the folder, and luckily there is only one such. It is the default behavior of almost all (basic) shells. If you write it however between single (`'*'`) or double (`"*"`) quotes, the shell does not *intepret* it, but passes it as a character.

So what basically happens is that your call, is replaced by the **cmd** to:

```
java Calculate 2 <files in the directory> 3
```

In other words, `java` doesn't even know you have ever used a wildcard, since it has been replaced **before** you called the program.

More info can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) (although the website is designed for *Linux* shells, the ideas are generally applicable).

**EDIT**

As @PatriciaShanahan argues you can also place the entire expression in quotes, like:

```
java Calculate "2 * 3"
```

Note however that in that case, `args[0]` will contain `"2 * 3"` (and the length of `args` will be `1`, thus you can't take benefit from the shell parsing your expression partly), so you will need to subdivide the string into parts yourself. And you don't drop the quotes completely.

Comment: yes I knew it is something like that, however my teacher insists that it has to be only * for multiplication, is there a way to override it?

Comment: @Jenny: no, at least not in general. You can of course use a shell (cmd) that is that basic wildcards are not supported. Note however that Java has no means to detect that wildcards are used, since the command line replaced it before passing control to Java.

Comment: @Jenny: what your teacher probably means is the solution PatriciaShanahan came up with, that the expression is passed as a full single string, and you need to do the subdivision yourself.

Comment: thanx, no my teacher coded last time in the 80s...I have a feeling he has no idea about this overloading...lol

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the entire calculation string in quotes, and split it yourself:

```
java Calculate "2 * 3"
```

That only uses a * for multiplication.

Comment: I think this would result in the entire expression be stored in `args[0]`. The program however *makes use* of the parsing capabilities of the shell.

Comment: It would indeed put the entire expression in `args[0]`. That is why you would have to spit it yourself, instead of depending on the shell to do it.

Comment: I think you need to go to the teacher, explain the issue, and ask for clarification.